# the unitary group of von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra and $P\in A'\subset B(H)$. Is it true that $U(A_P) =U(A)_p$?

Here $A_p$ is the von Neumann algebra containing all the element in the form of $XP$, $X\in A$, $U(A_p)$ is the unitary group of $A_P$ and $U(A)_p$ contains all the element  the unitaries of $A$ times $P$.

Comment: With unitary group of $A$ do you mean the unitaries that lie in $A$? I'm a little confused because then the elements of $U(A_P)$ are all unitary but none of the elements of $U(A)_P$ are unitary unless $P$ is unitary.

Comment: $U(A)_P$ is not the unitary group of $A$, all the elements in $U(A)_P$ are unitary in $A_P.$ @s.harp

Comment: You have explicitly written, $U(A_P)$ are the unitary elements of $A_P$ and $U(A)_P$ are the unitaries of $A$ times $P$.

Comment: @s.harp sure, thx

Comment: @Jonas Meyer  $U(A)_p$ means the unitary group of A "Multiple " p

Comment: @Jonas Meyer  well...we always call the set of all the unitary elements of a von Neumann algebra a unitary group, i didn't check it carefully. But i think they must satisfy all the conditions required to be a group.

Comment: You have not clarified my question, if $P$ is not unitary then _no element_ of $U(A)_P$ is unitary. On the other hand $U(A_P)$ always contains only unitaries. I think the definitions must thus be _different_.

Comment: @s.harp  elements $U(A)p$ are not unitary in $A$, but they are unitary in $A_p$, that is, for every $U\in U(A)p$, $U^*U=p$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see

[In induced von Neumann algebra, do we have $P(PMP) =P\cdot P(M)P$ and $U(PMP) =P\cdot U(M)P$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209792/in-induced-von-neumann-algebra-do-we-have-ppmp-p-cdot-pmp-and-upmp-p/2211171#2211171)