# two different unitary groups generate the same von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

This question may be a little weird. Every von Neumann algebra can be generated by its unitary group. However, I would like to ask, whether it is possible that two different unitary groups generate the same von Neumann algebra?

Comment: Could you state the problem more precisely?  I guess $\{1\}$ and $\{-1,1\}$ both generating $\mathbb{C}$ is not on your mind.

Comment: @westerbaan actually, i want to ask this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189073/the-unitary-group-of-von-neumann-algebra?noredirect=1#comment4505903_2189073